# Regex match 2 conditions

Tags: regex

Currently, I'm using this 2 regex on this WordPress plugin called redirection to filter out certain URL from being logged.

**(food)** to match anything containing food word anywhere in the URL.

**((.js)|(.css))$** to match any .js or .css at the end of URL

How do I combine this 2 regex into 1 with AND so I can get the expected output below?

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
https://example.com/food/test/apple.css - match
https://example.com/food/fruit/pineapple.css - match
https://example.com/food/fruit/apple.php - NOT match
https://example.com/food/new/strawberry.js - match
```

I've been trying this for hours but still can't make it work. I'm not good with Regex. How do I make it work with (food) AND ((.js)|(.css))$

I tried this combination below but failed. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
(food)&((.js)|(.css))$ 
(food)+((.js)|(.css))$ 
(food)/((.js)|(.css))$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
'~.*food.*\.(?:js|css)$~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/b5uLa1/2).

If `/food/` must be there use

```
'~.*/food/.*\.(?:js|css)$~'
```

If you are just testing for a match, remove the first `.*`.

**Details**

- `.*` - 0+ chars, as many as possible
- `food` - a literal substring
- `.*` - 0+ chars, as many as possible
- `\.(?:js|css)` - `.` followed with `js` or `css`
- `$` - end of string

Answer (score 0):

To match the word food anywhere in the url and make sure either .css or .js is at the end, you could join them using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

`^https?://.*food.*\.(?:css|js)$`

Using [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) that would be:

`'~^https?://.*food.*\.(?:css|js)$~'`

**Explanation**

- `^` Assert the start of the string
- `https?://` Match http with an optional s and then `://`
- `.*food.*` Match any character zero or more times, then match food followed by matching any character zero or more times
- `\.(?:css|js)$` Match a dot followed by a non capturing group which matches either css or js and assert the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iJpgta/1)

Comment: This works perfectly on Regex tester. But unfortunately its not working on my WordPress plugin.

Comment: @Null You have to use a delimiter other than a forward slash for example `~`. I have added that to my answer. If the urls are not at the start of the string you could omit the `^` anchor. and start with just `http`